# How can I count the number of items that where inserted at given time intervall to the DB?

Tags: mysql

All Columns have a timestamp from that I can get that information. I tried already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677333/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-database-for-different-time-periods)
but I don't get it to work!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if for example you want to group the number of occurences of a row by the hour part of the time stamp, try something like this (MySQL syntax):

```
select hour(TimeStamp) as interval, count(*) from data group by interval;
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
... WHERE timestamp > 1305211123 AND timestamp < 1305215094
```

This is for unix timestamp of course, if you have datefield instead it's pretty similar though.